# Сгенерировать все возможные варианты чисел

Tags: алгоритм

есть цифры от 1 до 8. нужно сгенерировать все возможные трехзначные числа из этих. Как можно это сделать?

P.S. Огромное спасибо всем, что ответил. У каждого свой интересный способ

Comment: Решение "в лоб" - три вложенных цикла, каждый из которых перебирает свой разряд

Comment: Тоже в лоб, но извращеннее: берете числа от 0 до 511, переводите в восьмеричную систему, добавляете к каждому разряду 1.

Comment: Спасибо. А более элегантных способов нету?

Comment: `read <$> replicateM 3 ['1'..'9']` достаточно элегантно? :) Алгоритм очень сильно зависит от исполнителя, другими словами, от языка программирования.

Answer (score 4):

На питоне:

```
from itertools import product

res = [int(''.join(triple)) for triple in product('12345678', repeat=3)]

print(res)
```

Этот код является решением, если в одном числе можно использовать одинаковые цифры (например `777`). Если же каждую цифру в числе можно использовать не более одного раза, то используйте `permutations` вместо `product` (но в этом случае параметр `repeat` нужно будет заменить на просто `r`)

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    char s[4] = "111";

    for (;;) {
        cout << s << endl;
        int carry = 0;

        if (++s[2] == '9') {
            s[2] = '1';
            carry = 1;
            }

        if (carry) {
            if (++s[1] == '9') {
                s[1] = '1';
                carry = 1;
                }
            else carry = 0;
            }

        if (carry) {
            if (++s[0] == '9') {
                s[0] = '1';
                carry = 1;
                }
            else carry = 0;
            }

        if (carry) break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Предложу еще один способ, не используя строк и символов.

Можно с помощь одного цикла. Если проанализировать последовательность, то мы заметим, что между десятками всегда будет "перескок" на 3 вперед

> (..., 117, 118, 121, 122..., 128, 131, ...).

А между сотнями - на 23

> (..., 187, 188, 211, ...).

Т.е. достаточно завести два счетчика на разряд единиц `rankConter0` и на разряд десятков `rankCounter1` и осуществлять "перескок", когда они превзойдут число 8.

Пример кода на C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var currentNum = 111;
    var rankCounter0 = 1;
    var rankCounter1 = 1;

    while (currentNum <= 888)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(currentNum); // Здесь выводим число, либо куда-то сохраняем

        rankCounter0++;

        if (rankCounter0 > 8)
        {
            currentNum += 3;
            rankCounter0 = 1;
            rankCounter1++;

            if (rankCounter1 > 8)
            {
                currentNum += 20;
                rankCounter1 = 1;
            }
        }    
        else
        {
            currentNum++;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Плюс** этого способа: если с этими числами нужно проводить какие-то вычисления, то отпадает необходимость переводить их в строки.

**Минус**: не универсален. Если нужно будет тоже самое сделать для N-значных чисел, то такой алгоритм не подойдет. Хотя мне кажется, его можно сделать универсальным.